# Is there a benefit to keeping old RSS entries in a feed?

Tags: xml, rss, rss-reader

I'm building a completely static, hand-coded webcomic website, which means my RSS feed will be updated by hand also. As "old" entries aren't really a concern due to the nature of the site, is there a reason I shouldn't just continuously reuse and update a single item in the feed, or should I keep them like a typical (machine-generated) feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow :)

I'd say that the main benefit, if I understood your context correctly, is archiving and posterity ?

What if a visitor wants to read your work from the beginning?

I'm sure you can easily automate the process somehow

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly!

Basically, the entire website is nothing but one big archive, so the feed only really exists to syndicate "The comic has updated!" with a link to http://web.comic/volume-number/#recent-pages (for example). All I'd have to do, essentially, is change the date of publication on the item.

I'm attempting a selfdogfood, but my knowledge begins and ends with HTML/CSS!

Comment: Well, RSS is XML so I believe "changing " any value in it could be done with a couple lines of javascript.... :)